# PCI compliance: using SSL as transport layer for RDP (Terminal Service)

Tags: windows, ssl, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

My client failed her PCI compliance audit. The server supports Remote Desktop (Terminal Service) but only provides encryption and not authentication. This exposes the server to Man-In-The-Middle attacks.

The supposed solution is to force SSL as the transport layer for RDP.

Anyone know how to do this?

The server runs Windows 2003.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895433

If the server has a cert from a trusted CA / Enterprise CA, skip to the section:

Step 2: Configure TLS authentication and encryption

Comment: hi yummy, i installed an SLL certificate using the following instructions, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816794#3.  but the certificate does not appear when i click "edit" from the "RDP-tcp Properties" dialog (when specifying a certificate for the SSL connection).  any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Windows Server 2008. Seriously - new RDP protocol, and TLS security is standard (at least I always get asked about whether to accept the unknown certificate between our domains - I have two domains that are not otherwise linked).

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the addition of [Network Level Authentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Level_Authentication) to RDP solves. I believe MS added it in Server 2008.